# How can I pass an array to a Django form

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to pass an array to my form that needs to be displayed as a select in my template, but the code I tried isn't working.

````
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.categs = kwargs.pop('categs')
        super(CheckForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    CHOICES = [(1,'Drop'),(2,'Mean'),(3,'Max'),(4,'Min')]
    missing = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Please indicate how you want to handle missing values', widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
    nametar = forms.CharField(label = 'Please indicate the name of the prediction')
    dropcol = forms.ArrayField(choices = categs, label = 'Please select the column you want to drop')```
````

Comment: regarding django docs, do we have `ArrayField` out there?

Comment: check this [one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield), may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this

```
CHOICES = [('1','Drop'),('2','Mean'),('3','Max'),('4','Min')]    
missing = forms.ChoiceField(label = 'Please i..', widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the choices after the form has been intitalized:

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):  
    self.categs = kwargs.pop('categs')
    _init=super(CheckForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    if self.categs:#or some other way of checking if categs exists
        self.fields["dropcol"].choices=self.categs
    return _init
    ...
```